# Socket.io/node.js on local network?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I have two machines on the same network say at 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3.

192.168.1.2 = server/dev pc

192.168.1.3 = client/browser pc

So on the server/dev pc I have a socket.io/http server running on port 82

On the client server I'm using chrome as the browser

The server is hosting a webpage like

```
<html>
....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
....
</html>
```

This is a necessary resource required for the socket.io client.  So the resource loads on my server/dev pc, but not on my client pc.  So I try:

```
<html>
....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.2:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
....
</html>
```

Now it doesn't work on either pc.  I know that it should be

```
<script src="http://<uri:port>/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

as it says on the socket.io github, but I want to only test on a local network.

I've also looked at

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
```

but I'm using socket.io 0.8.4 so the above version doesn't work.

So how can I get the socket.io resource served to the client in a local network environment? Or do you guys know of a website serving the 0.8.4 version of socket.io I could use?

Note: There are not firewall problems.

Comment: socket.io.js will only be server from the same machine your app is running, doesn't matter from what machine you are accessing it with.

Comment: @Marcel M. No wat r u talking about? They are used on online chat apps all the time

Comment: I meant using `localhost` will only work when server and client is the same machine, no matter the port

Comment: @MarcelM. I realize that, that's why it doesn't work, which is why I'm asking people for a way to run socket.io on a local network

Comment: What error message are you getting? Does "/socket.io/socket.io.js" exist from your web root dir on the server?

Answer (score 3):

Try letting socket.io connect automagically with

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a different port of the same host to serve socket.io you can try using

`<script>document.write('<script src="//'+ location.hostname + ':9998/socket.io/socket.io.js">\x3C/script>')</script>`

which looks like a hack but it works, just replace 9998 with the port you're serving socket.io with.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

with

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: that only works when both client and server are on the same machine

Comment: plz read https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client and also who +1ed this answer?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Because this answer looks correct to me. If it still doesn't work, check the network or console tab of the Chrome developer tools to see what causes the script request to fail.

Comment: this answer doesn't work. plz read  github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client, my machines are on the same network but are DIFFERENT machines, the above only works "If your web app and socket.io are on the same server and port"

Comment: it says so in the same page you link: "If your web app and socket.io are on the same server and port, you can simply include: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>"`

Comment: No, using localhost will only work if your client and server are in the same machine.

Comment: From your description, it reads as if your webpage/webapp and socket.io are both served from the same http server on port 82. If there's another webserver serving the page, *then* you'd usually include the host and port (`http://192.168.1.2:82`). You probably want to check the developer tools why the request is not coming through. (What error does it show there? Did you bind the server to localhost? Is there a firewall in between? We may need to see some code to help you out.)

Comment: It says "I have two machines on the same network" how did you get same http server from that?  This means one machine is the host and the other is the client.

Answer (score 0):

for the index:

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And from client connection:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3:82', {'forceNew': true});
```

this worked for me!.